# I cannot connect my e drum to pc

Tags: drums, electronic-drumset

So i bought an electronic drum Roland TD1DMK last month. Until now i don't know how to connect to my PC. I bought the jack and plug it in. It says that my drum just connect but when i check on my DAW, theres a notification that there are no MIDI input devices. Any solution please?

Comment: This sounds like a question for the customer service department of your DAW's maker. If you've already contacted them, please update your question with their suggestions, so that answers here won't repeat the same ideas you've already tried.

Comment: One thing puzzles me: are you trying to get the midi signal from the drum using a Jack cable?

Comment: What kind of computer are you using?  Does the "jack" (whatever that is) show up on the list of devices on the computer?